# Pushing a view controller from a tableview controller doesnt work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have setup a table view controller and connected a sub view so when I click on the rows the new subview appears. I followed a few tutorials step by step, but from some reason, nothing comes up when I click on the rows (the row is being selected though).

Here is my main view controller:

```
@interface TableViewsViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

IBOutlet UITableView *tblSimpleTable;
IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navBar;
NSArray *arryData;
NSMutableArray *listOfItems;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tblSimpleTable;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navBar;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *arryData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *listOfItems;
```

.m (relevant portions)

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

NSDictionary *dictionary = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Computers"];
NSString *cellValue = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath 
{

NSDictionary *dictionary = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Computers"];
NSString *selectedCountry = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//Initialize the detail view controller and display it.
DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
dvController.selectedComputer = selectedCountry;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
dvController = nil;

}
```

And the subview controller:

.h

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UILabel *lblText;
NSString *selectedComputer;


}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *lblText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *selectedComputer;

@end
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

//Display the selected country.
lblText.text = selectedComputer;

//Set the title of the navigation bar
self.navigationItem.title = @"Selected Computer";

}
```

I am pretty sure everything is well connected in IB.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does the navigationBar appear above the tableView before you select a row? The code looks correct, so I'd double check the connections and make sure that the navigationController is set up correctly.

Comment: Log `dvController` and see if it's `nil`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the table view inside a navigation controller. You can put a breakpoint on

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
```

and take a loot at the self.navigationController property. if it is nil, you will not be able to push anything onto it but it will not give you an error as sending a message to nil will merely return nil in most cases.

Comment: yes, it is nil....i realized i am not defining it at all...weird. I literally took it word by word from a tutorial.

Comment: A lot of times its the little things that mess you up the most. :)

Comment: I see that in many places they make some of those definitions in the AppDelegate - is that ok? While I am still a beginner, I try to never touch this object....thanks!

Comment: You app delegate is a possible place to put it. But a better solution would be a shared static object. so you create a class that has static method `+(MyHolder*) sharedHolder;` and in that method you would create a static copy of the class that would maintain the items you wanted to hold on to. Then you might also allow the "MyHolder" class to initialize items from places you need them if they are gone. and handle the Memory Deallocation when you get a memory warning.

Comment: Be sure to override the release and autorelease methods for the class contained in the static variable created with the shared method. this way it does not unintentionally get released

Answer (score 1):

Might be a small over look. If you created your DetailedViewController from a template and you check to create a nib file for it, the nib file should have the same name as the .h and .m files. So check for the name of your nib class. It might should be:

```
DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
```

P.S. use `self.` here:

```
self.dvController = nil;
```

Otherwise you will leak.

Comment: Funny, the initWithNibName was setup to another name actually (like I said, I copied this from a tutorial, but changed the file names), but once I fixed it, it still doesnt work.

Comment: Also Re leaking - do we still need this with ARC?